# How to save data from `console.log` to MySQL database?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, tensorflow

`

```
var imageScaleFactor = 0.5;
var outputStride = 16;
var flipHorizontal = false;

var imageElement = document.getElementById('video');

posenet.load().then(function(net){
  return net.estimateSinglePose(imageElement, imageScaleFactor, flipHorizontal, outputStride)
}).then(function(pose){
  console.log(pose);
})
```

`I wanna save that data to database. What should I do?

How to save data from `console.log` to MySQL database? I use PHP and JavaScript. I wanna save that data to a database. What should I do?

Comment: How are you displaying that data in your console?

Comment: keypoints: (17) […]
0: Object { score: 0.5010730028152466, part: "nose", position: {…} }
1: Object { score: 0.5042985677719116, part: "leftEye", position: {…} }
2: Object { score: 0.5008091926574707, part: "rightEye", position: {…} }

3: Object { score: 0.5006607174873352, part: "leftEar", position: {…} }

4: Object { score: 0.49880221486091614, part: "rightEar", position: {…} }

Comment: how to send value score and part to database? Thank you for answer

Comment: Hey and welcome to SO! You can help others help you by providing code examples that clearly illustrate what you have already tried and where you got stuck. This greatly increases the chance of a user being able to solve your particular problem.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could create a PHP handler that you could send the console.log() JS dump to via an ajax POST. That's the only way to bridge the gap I could think of.

In your Javascript you could override the built-in `console.log` function to accomplish this:

```
console.log = function(value){
    ...
    // do your ajax post here sending value to your php script that writes it to the db
    ...
};
```